# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Process 6 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, sql, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4302.0 (X64)` (Latest CU11, Feb 2014) on `Windows Server 2012 R2`.

I have a simple database and a website that runs on the same machine using IIS. The server has 24 GB DDR3 memory and a XEON processor.

When I was testing the website on this server, I had the following error message on the website (from a sql query error):

[image]

So, I thought there was something wrong with my website code and checked that, there was nothing in there. So I decided to run the query manually in SQL Management Studio, so when I launched that up and clicked on connect button, I got the following error:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476
```

This is when I started to look at the SQL Server logs found at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG`

This is the file's content: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TsiYHxNi

More logs from the server can be found here (including crash dump) : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51720218/mssql_logs_dumps.zip

Any idea how to fix this? I am already running the latest cumulative update available to my version of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Is there a problem with my database? or is there a problem with the way my DB Server is setup?

In order to fix this issue, I opened services and tried to restart "SQL Server" and it results in the following further error:

[image]

So to fix this error, I now have to restart the physical machine. Any help on this error will be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8603111/225906